# How get the value of textbox control created in runtime, inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm working with asp.net, and i have a gridview with some rows as textboxes. I want to know how to get the value of a textbox if those textboxes are created in runtime and the id are default values, therefore I can not access the FindControl method because I do not have the id of textboxes.

Comment: Add every textbox to you create to some list?

Comment: Could you show us what you have done?

Comment: Use FindControl: `TextBox tb = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox`